# Anaconda environments with python 3.6 not working

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

My anaconda environment has the following error when I try to use python in this environment from the terminal:

```
(py36torch) pc@pc:~$ python

Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pc/anaconda3/envs/py36torch/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 703, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/pc/anaconda3/envs/py36torch/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 670, in main
    virtual_install_main_packages()
  File "/home/pc/anaconda3/envs/py36torch/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 553, in virtual_install_main_packages
    f = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'orig-prefix.txt'))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pc/anaconda3/envs/py36torch/lib/python3.6/orig-prefix.txt'
```

I checked my environment of python-3.7, it is working fine. Has anyone come across such an issue? I am not sure how to fix this. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you mixing `virtualenv` with `conda`? AFAIK, `orig-prefix.txt` is a virtualenv thing and Conda doesn't use such a file.

Comment: I figured it out just sometime ago. Fixed it, although I had to reset my `conda` env. It was my mistake. I created an environment using `virtualenv` while working in `conda` env. I was setting up [`drake`](https://drake.mit.edu/) and this happened because I missed an installation instruction of disabling `conda`. Is there a way to fix it without recreating your `conda env`? Thanks.

Comment: yeah I'm not sure. It sounds like Conda was still working though, so hopefully you could simply dump out the env.yaml (`conda env export`) and recreate it from that (`conda env create -f`).

Comment: Yes. I did the same thing. Thanks.